# d3 js tooltip on hover treenode not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

Here is my code for displaying a tooltip when I mouseover on a tree node .

```
function mouseover(d) {
                d3.select(this).append("div")
                    .attr("class","tooltip")
                    .attr('transform', function(d){ 
                        return 'translate(5, -10)';
                    })
                    .text(d.name);
            }
```

and here is my css for the tooltip itself

```
.tooltip {
            display: inline;
            position: relative;
        }

        .tooltip:hover {
            color: #c00;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .tooltip:hover:after {
            background: #111;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
            border-radius: .5em;
            bottom: 1.35em;
            color: #fff;
            content: attr(title);
            display: block;
            left: 1em;
            padding: .3em 1em;
            position: absolute;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
            white-space: nowrap;
            z-index: 98;
        }

        .tooltip:hover:before {
            border: solid;
            border-color: #111 transparent;
            border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8) transparent;
            border-width: .4em .4em 0 .4em;
            bottom: 1em;
            content: "";
            display: block;
            left: 2em;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 99;
        }
```

I am not able to see the tooltip when I  mouse over the node.  I am fairly new to d3.

What could the issue be ?

Answer (score 0):

i create demo for you

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr('height', '300px')
  .attr('width', '300px')

var bg = svg.append("g")
  .append('rect')
  .attr('height', '300px')
  .attr('width', '300px')
  .attr('fill', '#F00');

var tooltip = svg.append("g")
 .append('rect')
  .attr('height', '50px')
  .attr('width', '50px')
  .attr('fill', '#0F0');
  
bg.on('mousemove', function() {
var x = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 25;
var y = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 70
    tooltip
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```